# React Objects are not valid as a React child error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out what could be causing the error "Objects are not valid as a React child" in my code. This is what I have so far:

```
render() {
let showAddons = [];
            let addons = 0;
            if (typeof this.props.photoPackage.addons !== 'undefined'){
                if (typeof this.props.photoPackage.addons.Night !== 'undefined'
                    && this.props.photoPackage.addons.Night.isNight){
                    const price = this.props.photoPackage.addons.Night.price;
                    addons = addons + price;

                    showAddons.push(<li key={1}>Night Photos ${price}</li>)
                }
                if (typeof this.props.photoPackage.addons.Drone !== 'undefined'
                    && this.props.photoPackage.addons.Drone.isDrone){
                    const price = this.props.photoPackage.addons.Drone.price;
                    addons = addons + price;
                    showAddons.push(<li key={2}>Drone Photos ${price}</li>);

                }

return (
<div>
    {showAddons} //This causes the error
</div>
)}
```

The showAddons variable is what is causing the issue, but I can't figure out why. The price const in both if statements resolves to 99, I checked them by logging them to the console. I did something very similar on another component and it works just fine:

```
render() {
let currentMonth = moment(this.state.year + '-' + this.state.month + '-' + 0o1);
            let times = [];
            let date = moment(this.state.chosenDate);
            console.log('Date ', date.format('DD'));
            for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.state.times).length; i++){
                const day = moment(
                    date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                    + ' ' + this.state.times[i],
                    'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mmA');

               times.push(<li key={i} onClick={(e) => {
                    this.handleAddDateTime(day.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A'))


             }} className={"acuity_times"}>{day.format('h:mm A')} {(day.format ('h:mm A') === '6:00 PM' || day.format ('h:mm A') === '8:00 PM') ? '(+$99)' : ''}</li>)
            }

return (

   <div>
   {times} //This works without errors
   </div>


)}
```

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated.

Update:

I have console.log() both the working and not working arrays and I took a photo of the console displaying the first object in both instances. I don't know if it will help, but it might give some more insight:

[image]

This is the first object returned from the times array, which is the one that works as expected with no errors.

[image]

This is the first object returned in the showAddons array, the one that produces the error. As you can see, they are both objects, but only showAddons is having the issue, whereas the times array works as expected.

Comment: Firstly, your code formatting are really bad and it's hard to read your code. Consider refactoring after you solve where the issue lays. Later you will have difficulties understanding what is going on in your code.
Secondly, try to console.log `showAddons` just before return and edit your question with output

Comment: @lomboboo Thanks for the advice. The way I have it formatted here is not how it's formatted in the actual code. It's more of a strict copy paste, but it doesn't always keep the same formatting when I do that.

Comment: I'm not talking only about formatting question but also your actual code is unreadable. All the calculation array population does not really belong to `render` method. Consider separate method inside class. For example, `formatDate()`, `getDay()`, `populateAddons()`

Comment: Something within showAddons is an object.  `console.log` that to see whats in there.

Comment: Mark Swardstrom I tried that already as well. In both the working and not working instances, they return as an array of objects but only one of them has an issue with it it seems. Functionally, as far as I can tell, the working and not working instances are the same.

Comment: try to remove one of the `if` statements. Also I suggest you to create basic example in jsfiddle or something that reproduces your issue. Because it is not clear what are `state` values and `props` values.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) I created basic example of your code. Edit it the way that reproduces the issue and I will help you

Answer (score 0):

Should it be `()` around return result instead of `{}` for normal React syntax?

I cannot get your second render function running without the same error. I'm assuming your second function is a `getItems` render function so it can return an array.

If so, you should wrap your `{showAddons}` inside a html tag or a React component.

```
return (
  <div>
    {showAddons} //This causes the error
  </div>
)
```

You can replace `div` tag with `React.Fragment` if you're using react 16.2 or later.

Comment: You are correct and I made a mistake when adding in return, but in my original code, it is surrounded by parentheses. I'm gonna change it now.